# nyromodal enter key, how to disable it. (iframe refresh call)

Tags: jquery, nyromodal

When overlay modal is opened, if i hit enter key, iframe refresh is called. I can not figure out how to disable that. Any help would be much appreciated.

This is the only resource i found about this issue so far: http://code.google.com/p/nyromodal/issues/detail?id=271

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with nyromodal, do you have an example you can link to where it's doing that? nyromodal website demos don't do that when I hit the enter key.

Comment: I do not have linkable example. i just know that DOM filter is responsible for this behavior, and i am not sure how to turn it off within that filter, because i do need that filter still. freaking documentation sucks, the whole damn plugin is an overkill, i just dont have luxury of switching to something else.

Comment: found solution, i trigger blur on link element after modal is resized that fixes it. Rather screwed up solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.nyroModal').nyroModal({
    closeOnClick: false,
    closeButton: "<span class='nyroModalClose'>CLOSE</span>",
    callbacks: {
        beforeShowCont: function(nm) { 
            Cufon.replace('span.nyroModalClose', { color: '#015eb3', fontFamily: 'UniversCondensed' });
            $('#modal-respass .show-reset').show();
            $('#modal-respass .show-thank-you').hide();
        },
        afterShowCont: function(nm) {
            $('.nyroModalCont').css({'height':'auto'});
            /* this is the eval ==> */$('a').blur();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: found solution, i trigger blur on link element after modal is resized that fixes it. Rather screwed up solution...